# AWS Api Gateway User: anonymous is not authorized to perform

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a quite simple private API Gateway setup. Now I want to call it from an EC2 instance with a curl command. Therefor I created a VPC Endpoint and connected it to the API GW.
I set a resource policy on allowing everything on the VPCE. I also allow the sourceIP Adress of my EC2 instance on my API GW.

I can see my curl calls in cloudwatch on the API GW, so I assume that the VPCE isn't the problem. Also my backend integration seems to work: The Test in AWS console returns correct values of my backend.

Here is my export swagger:

```
    ---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "Provides all backend operations"
  version: "0.7.0"
  title: "xxx"
host: "xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
basePath: "/dev"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  /xxx/yyy:
    get:
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "200 response"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GlobalPreferences"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: "http"
        connectionId: "a3sz11"
        httpMethod: "GET"
        uri: "https://bla/xxx/yyy"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
        timeoutInMillis: 5000
        tlsConfig:
          insecureSkipVerification: true
definitions:
  GlobalPreferences:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      language:
        type: "string"
        enum:
        - "DE"
        - "UK"

x-amazon-apigateway-policy:
  Version: "2012-10-17"
  Statement:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Principal: "*"
    Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
    Resource: "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:aaa:bbb/*"
    Condition:
      IpAddress:
        aws:SourceIp: "w.x.y.z"
x-amazon-apigateway-endpoint-configuration:
  vpcEndpointIds:
  - "vpce-123456789"
```

On running this command:

```
curl https://bbb-vpce-123456789.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/xxx/yyy
```

I keep getting "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform" Error. In cloudwatch I can see the correct source IP Adress w.x.y.z

Answer (score 0):

We've found the issue. Our DNS Server resolved the URL from the curl command incorrectly. The call arrived at the API Gateway, but it didn't use the desired endpoint.